# Setup Sitecore 7.1 using SQL Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, installation, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

How can I install Sitecore 7.1 using SQL Server windows credentials?  It's asking for SQL Server Authentication but I have Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 things you need to set to allow Sitecore using Windows Authentication while connection to MSSQL Server database:

1. Allow chosen user account on the SQL Server
2. Set Application Pool for your Web Application to use your chosen user account as Identity
3. Set `Integrated Security=True` in your `ConnectionStrings.config` file

Comment: This is a good answer to the question "How do I run Sitecore using a trusted SQL Server connection?".  Unfortunately, that's not what the question was.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Windows Domain Credentials with the Sitecore Installer unfortunately.  It will only accept SQL Credentials.  You have two ways around this limitation.

1) Use the Sitecore Installation program with a temporary SQL credential.  Once the install is complete manually update the Application Pool Credentials to a Domain user and then update your ConnectionStrings.config file to remove the username and password fields and setting Integrated Security=True or Trusted_Connection=true in your connection string.

2) Manually install Sitecore with the ZIP of the site root (available on SDN) following the Sitecore Installation Guide found here -> http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Installation%20Guide.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sitecore Instance Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Instance_Manager.aspx).  When entering your SQL credentials, just uncheck the box labeled Use SQL Server Login.